# Wpf Datagrid :Catch duplicated entry on datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a datagrid which is binded using the ObservableCollection .If the user  made a duplicated entry on a cell then I want to validate against the whole collection , for example in my datagrid I put a DatagridComboboxColumn to select Items ,if the user select an item which is already exist on the datagrid then ,I want to put some visual feedback with message 'the selected item already exist' How to accomplish this ?
my xaml is :

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="dgPurchaseReturnEntry" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
             >
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
       <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                       Width="300"
                       Header="Product Name"
                       SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Id,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                                                       
                       SelectedValuePath="Product_Id"
                       DisplayMemberPath="Product_Name"                                           
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductDataProvider}}">
            <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
                </Style>

            </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

my object is:

```
 public class clsPurchaseBillEntryList : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{

    private int _Product_Id;

    #region Property Getters and Setters

    public int Product_Id
    {
        get { return _Product_Id; }
        set
        {
            _Product_Id = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Product_Id");
        }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    // Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
            // iterate over all of the properties
            // of this object - aggregating any validation errors
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                string propertyError = this[prop.Name];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyError))
                {
                    error.Append(propertyError);
                }
            }
            return error.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (name == "Qty")
            {

            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    }
}
```

How do I catch the duplicated entry on the datagrid ?